# Checking more than one condition and storing values

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem that is driving me nuts. It should be straightforward, because I have done it many times before, but for some odd reason it is not working now...

**Background**

I am doing a few checks on some columns. If a value in each of the columns is found to be True, then boolean markers will be switched to False.

There are 3x columns to check and 3x boolean markers.

At the end, I check status of these boolean markers and get an output.

**Code**

```
Dim TfPCheck as boolean
Dim CentreV as boolean
Dim FlaggedTasks as boolean
Dim AddtionalInfoCheck As Boolean

TfPCheck= True
CentreV = True
FlaggedTasks = True
AdditionalInfoCheck = True

With Worksheets("Admin")
    For i = 7 To LR
        If .Cells(i, 12) = "True" Then
        TfPCheck = False
        Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    End With

    With Worksheets("Admin")
    For i = 7 To LR
        If .Cells(i, 14) = "True" Then
        CentreV = False
        Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    End With

    With Worksheets("Admin")
    For i = 7 To LR
        If .Cells(i, 16) = "True" Then
        FlaggedTasks = False
        Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    End With


    If TfPCheck = True And CentreV = True And FlaggedTasks = True Then
    AdditionalInfoCheck = True

    ElseIf TfPCheck = False And CentreV = True And FlaggedTasks = True Then
    addtionalInfoCheck = False

    ElseIf TfPCheck = True And CentreV = False And FlaggedTasks = True Then
    addtionalInfoCheck = False

    ElseIf TfPCheck = True And CentreV = True And FlaggedTasks = False Then
    addtionalInfoCheck = False

    ElseIf TfPCheck = False And CentreV = True And FlaggedTasks = False Then
    addtionalInfoCheck = False

    ElseIf TfPCheck = False And CentreV = False And FlaggedTasks = True Then
    addtionalInfoCheck = False

    ElseIf TfPCheck = True And CentreV = False And FlaggedTasks = False Then
    addtionalInfoCheck = False

    ElseIf TfPCheck = False And CentreV = False And FlaggedTasks = False Then
    addtionalInfoCheck = False

    End If

    MsgBox (AdditionalInfoCheck)
```

Am I doing something wrong? Because AddtionalInfoCheck comes back as True, when it shouldn't.

Thanks

Comment: Aren't the checks for true in columns L, N & P supposed to be in the same row? You have it matching true for each column anywhere from row 7 to lr.

Comment: You could have a True in Col(L) Row(20), and a True in Col(N), Row(8).. They do not have to be True in the same Row...

Comment: As a side note, you can determine additionalInfoCheck more concisely as additionalInfoCheck = tfPCheck And CentreV And FlaggedTasks i.e. assigns additionalInfoCheck to be true only if all those variables are true.

Comment: @JohnF Do you mean I should not initialize it as true in the beginning?

Comment: @OdaySalim No, although it is not necessary. What I am saying is that your if...elseif..end if is saying additionalInfoCheck is True only if TfPCheck, CentreV and FlaggedTasks are all true (correct me if I am wrong). The whole If..Elseif can be replaced simply by the line additionalInfoCheck = tfPCheck And CentreV And FlaggedTasks.

Comment: Use Option Explicit. AdditionalInfoCheck is spelled two different ways.

Comment: @Jeeped what does Option Explicit do? and thank you.

Comment: It requires that you declare all variables. It also catches spelling errors like this one. Go into the vbe's Tools, Options and put a check beside Require variable declaration. After that, Option Explicit will be at the top of every new code sheet.

Comment: Also, declare with camel-case vars like you did but type them as lower case later on. Ones that are spelled correctly will change to match the camel-case, misspelled ones will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is going to resolve your issue but it seems that all of your code can be boiled down to the following.

```
    Dim TfPCheck As Boolean, CentreV As Boolean, FlaggedTasks As Boolean
    Dim LR As Long, AdditionalInfoCheck As Boolean

    With Worksheets("Admin")
        LR = Application.Max(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row, _
                             .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row, _
                             .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row)
        TfPCheck = IsError(Application.Match(True, .Range(.Cells(7, "L"), .Cells(LR, "L")), 0))
        CentreV = IsError(Application.Match(True, .Range(.Cells(7, "N"), .Cells(LR, "N")), 0))
        FlaggedTasks = IsError(Application.Match(True, .Range(.Cells(7, "P"), .Cells(LR, "P")), 0))
    End With

    AdditionalInfoCheck = CBool(TfPCheck And CentreV And FlaggedTasks)
```

Use Option Explicit. AdditionalInfoCheck was spelled two different ways.